# Prestashop Error (module instaliation)

Tags: prestashop

I was installing a module on PrestaShop and saw an error that you can not install this module:

```
Unknown error line 133 in file /home/malaghe/public_html/modules/productedit/productedit.php
[2048] Declaration of ProductEdit::displayFlags() should be compatible with ModuleCore::displayFlags($languages, $default_language, $ids, $id, $return = false, $use_vars_instead_of_ids = false)
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

thank you

Comment: any body can help?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the two methods declarations cited in the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit file

/home/malaghe/public_html/modules/productedit/productedit.php

function displayFlags ( ... )

-> edit here to enought 6 params like Prestashop Core

/home/malaghe/public_html/classes/module/Module.php

public function displayFlags($languages, $default_language, $ids, $id, $return = false, $use_vars_instead_of_ids = false)

Answer (score 0):

I think Tuan Vu is right. 
Add 6 params to your ProductEdit::displayFlags() function.